# How can I script an update to a servicemix system bundle using karaf's client.bat?

Tags: powershell, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

How can I script out a update to a servicemix system bundle using karaf's client.bat? When I try to run `./client.bat "update 111" -p <password>` through powershell I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. I believe it is because updating this bundle requires the user to type yes on the server when it asks "You are about to access system bundle 111.  Do you wish to continue (yes/no):" Any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Specify user and password first then specify command you want to run.

**Example:**

```
# Default user and password
./client.bat -u karaf -p karaf -- "update 111"
```

Don't recall Apache Karaf asking for confirmation when it comes to `bundle:update`. If service mix has such thing you might want to check `bundle:update --help` to see if there's option to skip it.